# How to assign to referenced object

Tags: c#

I have two lists of object

```
 [Serializable]
 private class MemorySet
 {
    public Dictionary<string, object> _Map;
    public List<object> _Results;
    public List<object> _Storage;
 }
 MemorySet Memory = new MemorySet();
```

I can have keys assigned for an object, for example

```
    _Map.Add("someKey", _Results[_Results.Count - 1]);
```

I have a method

```
private object Mapper(string key)
{
    if (Memory._Map.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        return Memory._Map[key];
    }
    else if (key.ToLower() == "result")
    {
        return Memory._Results[Memory._Results.Count - 1];
    }
    else if (key.ToLower() == "storage")
    {
        return Memory._Storage[Memory._Storage.Count - 1];
    }
    else if (key.ToLower().Contains("result"))
    {
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(key.ToLower().Split(new string[] { "result" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]);
        return Memory._Results[n];
    }
    else if (key.ToLower().Contains("storage"))
    {
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(key.ToLower().Split(new string[] { "storage" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]);
        return Memory._Storage[n];
    }
    else return null;
}
```

Now I must assign to an object from _Storage or _Results like that:

```
object obj = key != "" ? Mapper(key) : Memory._Storage[Memory._Storage.Count - 1];
if(obj is string) obj as string = "test";
```

this will change obj to reference some new string in memory. But I want to change the object that obj references to instead.

In other words obj will become "test", but the underlying object won't be changed.

I understand why that happends, though I didn't imagine it that way when writing the whole engine, and now I have big trouble with that one. In C++ we have pointers, but in C# I don't want to use GCHandles or unmanaged code for that trivial stuff, would be extremely ugly.

So, how to assign to the object that object points to, instead assigning to the object itself?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here, but I will tell you that you're correct: pointers to pointers are not comfortable in C#. That said, and I know this doesn't mean much, but I've never run into this problem before. I'd probably take a step back and question whether this is the right way to go about solving this problem in the first place. It seems complicated and prone to bugs, but that's just my opinion. Perhaps forcing those diverse operations into a single vaguely-typed method isn't the best way to architect this.

Comment: Well in few words I have methods that assign here or there, and I need a method that tells where to assign based on some criteria. Problem is, I can't pass objects like that

Comment: Your naming convention is pretty nonstandard. Typically public properties or fields just start with a capital letter. Private properties or fields start with an underscore and then lowercase letter. Its not a big deal but just something it looks like you may not be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[Serializable]
    private class MemorySet
    {
        public Dictionary<string, object> _Map = new Dictionary<string,object>();
        public List<object> _Results = new List<object>();
        public List<object> _Storage = new List<object>)_;
    }
```

Comment: The dictionary and List<> need to call a constructor (with new) before adding data.  You are trying to add the data before calling a constructor.

Comment: I do that elsewhere, but that would throw null reference, would be obvious, don't you think

Comment: Yes it should throw null reference.  Reading you question again I don't think you need to worry about the pointers.  The List<> doesn't add object to list but instead creates a pointer to the object.  If you make a copy of a list in c# and change one of the copies the value in both lists get changed.  You have to clone the list to get two distinct copies of the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with your current design, you could just add a method that would update your data structures on the same template as your `Mapper` method. This is what it would look like:

```
private void Update(string key, object value)
{
  if (Memory._Map.ContainsKey(key))
  {
    Memory._Map[key] = value;
  }
  else if (key.ToLower() == "result")
  {
    Memory._Results[Memory._Results.Count - 1] = value;
  }
  else if (key.ToLower() == "storage")
  {
    Memory._Storage[Memory._Storage.Count - 1] = value;
  }
  else if (key.ToLower().Contains("result"))
  {
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(key.ToLower().Split(new string[] { "result" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]);
    Memory._Results[n] = value;
  }
  else if (key.ToLower().Contains("storage"))
  {
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(key.ToLower().Split(new string[] { "storage" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]);
    Memory._Storage[n] = value;
  }
  else
  {
    throw new ArgumentException("Failed to compute valid mapping", nameof(key));
  }
}
```

Maybe you could also add the `key == ""` pattern in there, I'm not sure to understand how this would be used exactly, but hopefully you get the idea.

**EDIT:** OK, so references to the same object are used in different structures. You should consider to design a `MemorySet` that avoids this. If you still think this is the proper design considering your needs, you have a simple solution: wrap your target objects in other objects.

```
public class ObjectWrapper
{
  public object ObjectOfInterest { get; set; }
}
```

Now you store `ObjectWrapper` objects. Then you can update the property `ObjectOfInterest` and this change will be reflected to all structures that contain this `ObjectWrapper`:

```
ObjectWrapper wrapper = Mapper(key);
wrapper.ObjectOfInterest = "test";
```

Comment: This won't work either because Memory._Map[key] = value; will set the corresponding object in the dictionary, not the one in the list